# How to overlap an image over p:graphic image dynamically

Tags: jsf, primefaces

[image]

I have Primefaces 6 application where I already display images using the following tag in xhtml. In the below tag, cuapp.logo will have MyImage picture.
My current requirement is to include a bubble in the right most corner with values populated dynamically from backend and the value of this will be present in cuapp.count.
I need help on this requirement.

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{ImageFinder.convertByteArrayToImage(cuapp.logo)}"
                                        stream="false" styleClass="image" ></p:graphicImage>
```

Comment: Your problem is not a JSF problem. It's a plain HTML/CSS problem. You would still have had exactly the same problem with any other server-side framework which produces HTML pages such as PHP/ASP/etc. I recommend to reframe your question to base off client-side HTML output, not the server-side JSF source code and then retarget HTML/CSS folks.

Comment: If you can upgrade your PF version you could use https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/badge/basicUsage.jsf